# How enable MathJax functionality on Heroku

Tags: heroku, web-applications, mathjax

I am kinda new to both the Python language and the Heroku web interface to web-app deployment. My background is engineering, and MATLAB programming so the whole rails/web scene is new to me. But I am trying to learn the basics for an upcoming project. Towards this end, with the help of a few tutorials around the web, I have managed to successfully couple of Python/NumPy + Flask based apps:

https://matrix-spectrum.herokuapp.com/

https://plot-damped-sinusoid.herokuapp.com/

But as you can already see, in the second link, the LaTeX/MathJax mark-up is not displaying correctly. Whenever I run it on my localhost it works correctly (`heroku local web`), but once it is deployed that MathJax does not display.

How do I fix this? Why isn't adding:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
     equationNumbers: {  autoNumber: "AMS"  },
     extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "autobold.js", "color.js"]
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

in the header working? The closest question/answer I can find is:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/Rpa_WQ6rMkE

But that is about 5 years, old and I suspect there should be more recent developments like:

https://github.com/pmq20/mathjax-rails

But I have no experience with "rails".

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links use the HTTPS (encrypted HTTP) protocol, but modern browsers often refuse to load unencrypted content if the main connection is encrypted. This is called [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).

Your link to load the MathJax library hard-codes an unencrypted HTTP connection:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

You *could* switch `http://` for `https://`, but a better approach is probably to simply use `//`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

This makes your link *protocol-relative*; it will load using the same protocol as the page itself.

I encourage you to learn about your [browser](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)'s [developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) [tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx), which are a great resource when doing web development. The console included there often reveals this type of problem.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.